# How to set multiple reactive values and shiny outputs to NULL?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to set a few shiny output elements and reactive values to NULL, perhaps with a loop like this:

```
itemsToNull <- c("output$plot1", "output$plot2", 
                 "reactVal$react1", "reactVal$react2")

for (i in itemsToNull) {
    assign(i, NULL)
}
```

or similar but different:

```
itemsToNull <- list("output$plot1", "output$plot2", 
                 "reactVal$react1", "reactVal$react2")

for (i in 1:length(itemsToNull)) {
    assign(itemsToNull[[i]], NULL)
}
```

Neither of those work, so I've been doing it 'manually':

```
output$plot1    <- NULL
output$plot2    <- NULL
reactVal$react1 <- NULL
reactVal$react2 <- NULL
```

Surely there is a more elegant solution I'm not aware of?

Comment: Would `output[["plot1"]] <- NULL` work? If not I'm thinking of eval-parse but get a headache just by thinking about it.

Comment: Why would you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: @Sada93, in short: I want my shiny app to subset its data input and re-run several analyses on the subsetted data. Some of these analyses and their outputs are triggered by buttons. So I find my plots displaying "stale" data and would like to nullify them when my input is subsetted. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `reset()` function from library([shinyjs](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/reset.html)) - but this assumes your inputs were initialized with NULL.